# Display Image in Kendo Grid : Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4, telerik, web-config

In order to display an image saved as binary in dabatase i do the following:

```
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(c => c.Title).Width(420).ClientTemplate(string.Format("{0}...", "#= formatter(Title) #"));
    columns.Bound(c => c.Text).Width(900).ClientTemplate(string.Format("{0}...", "#= formatter(Text) #"));
    columns.ForeignKey(p => p.languageId, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["lang"], "Id", "Name").Title("Language").Width(140).EditorTemplateName("LangDropDown");
    columns.Bound(p => p.Image64).ClientTemplate("<img src='data:image/png;base64,#=Image64#' />").Title("Base64 Images");
    columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); });

})
```

My model:

```
[Display(Name = "Photo")]  
public byte[] img { get; set; }
public string Image64
{
    get
    {
        return img != null ? Convert.ToBase64String(img) : null;
    }
}
```

When i load the page, the grid appears empty and when i try to get more informations with the console tab of my browser, i see the following error :

> Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON
>   JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set
>   on the maxJsonLength property.

I tried to add this in my web.config :

```
       <system.web.extensions>
           <scripting>
               <webServices>
                   <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>
               </webServices>
           </scripting>
       </system.web.extensions>
```

and

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="2147483647" />
```

But none of those solutions work. Any help would be welcome!
Thanks

Comment: I found a solution by overriding the json method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by overriding the json method